# JSONSerialization AnyObject SWIFT3 Conversion Issues

Tags: ios, swift3, nsjsonserialization

I have converted to Swift 3 and I have received the following errors when assigning to AnyObject the JSONSerialization.jsonObject. Has anyone come across this issue and know the fix?

[image]

Comment: Post actual code, not an image of the code. People often want to reproduce your code to try and troubleshoot it

Answer (score 0):

Since the last **Swift 3** update most of the return types changed from `AnyObject` to `Any` and downcast is not allowed, so in such situation you are forced to use explicit cast. That means you should make a couple of `guard` statements or use optional chaining `if let` defining each necessary field. Consider using `map`, `filter`, `reduce` if possible to make your code more elegant. Example:

`guard` way:

```
guard let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]] else { return nil }
guard let field1 = object[0]["field1_token"] as? [Any] else { return nil }
//do your thing
```

`if let` way:

```
if let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]],
let field1 = object[0]["field1_token"] as? [Any] {
//do your thing
}
```

You may want to check Apple's article [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37&utm_campaign=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly&utm_medium=web&utm_source=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_268)

Also you can use some of the json parsing/mapping libriaries like these:

[SwiftyJSON](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON)

[Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss)

Answer (score -1):

Please replace `let object : AnyObject` with `let object : Any`.

Error showing because of wrong casting.